# Link to PDF opens blank - PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, pdf, jquery-mobile

My webapp, which was created using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile, contains a link to a PDF file.  Currently the code says

```
<a href="my-file.pdf" data-ajax=false target="_blank">Open File</a>
```

When I click the link, a PDF viewer opens.  The right number of pages is displayed, but they are all blank.

**Update**

I believe my previous problem was caused by PhoneGap, and that I should instead use PhoneGap's InAppBrowser Plugin.

Following these instructions, I now have this function:

```
function goToFile() {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('my-file.pdf', '_blank');
}
```

However, like before, the PDF opens, but every page is blank.

**Another Update**

I discovered that the PDF only showed up blank when I linked to the PDF using a relative path or the absolute path from my localhost.  When I linked to version of the PDF we have hosted on Github Pages, it showed up fine.

I would still like to know why the line of code above does not work, though.

Comment: When you navigate to the PDF directly, is it blank? Or you only see this when it's loaded via your app?

Comment: Only when loaded on the app.

Comment: Any errors in the console when you call the PDF or do you see the PDF trying to load other resources?

Comment: Is this a Static PDF or is it generated dynamically?

Comment: It's a static PDF, and I don't get any errors.

Comment: That's very strange. If the path was wrong, I expect you'd get a 404 style error. How are you testing? Can you emulate a mobile app and see if you get more details from logs or activity? I can't think of why the PDF is not displaying content.

Comment: The PDF opens correctly on a mobile phone, but shows a blank PDF on mobile browsers.  I don't see any useful log information from either.

Comment: So the mobile browser is unable to parse the pdf content. Which browsers are you testing with?

Comment: On my phone, I've tried it on Safari and Chrome.  On my laptop, I've tried it on Chrome and Firefox.